# How can I make a simple climate simulator?

Tags: simulations, climate-science

Given an Earth-like planet with arbitrary terrain, how can I create a simple climate simulator that can output parameters such as humidity and temperature, so that I can assign biomes to areas of land?

My knowledge of climate modelling approaches zero, so to take a step back: is such a simple model even possible (i.e. one accessible to hobbyists), if so are there examples, if not where can I get started?

My motivation is that, it seems to me that a lot of fictional worlds were created without applying climate models. Their creators often apply a [very simple model](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/) (e.g. things are wet near the seas and get drier inland), most don't even try to determine things like rain shadows. I thought that we could improve a lot on this situation by applying some simple climate science principles. With this motivation in mind, I'm aiming more for verisimilitude than rigor.

[This recent story about some climate scientists modelling the climate of Middle Earth](http://bristol.ac.uk/news/2013/10013.html) is in line with what I'm aiming for, although I read that they used HadCM3L which doesn't seem like something accessible to laymen.

---

To show what I've tried so far, I've done a bit of reading and come up with the following. It's been difficult for me because I'm a novice, and also a lot of available material seems to be focused on the climate change issue. Perhaps Paleoclimatology is more relevant? I have no idea.

- Prevailing winds, caused by Hadley cells, and affect cloud movement and creates surface currents and gyres
- Deep ocean currents, caused by salt and temperature differences near the poles and circulates globally, which combines with the gyres to form warm current flows
- Air masses, whose temperature and humidity are determined by whether they're over land or sea, create weather fronts and lots of precipitation between them
- Mountain ranges that, in the presence of humidity-carrying winds, cause orthographic lift and rain shadows afterwards

I have no idea whether this is on the right track, and even if so, how far the rabbit hole goes (e.g. do I have to worry about the influence of [moons/tides](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83574/does-the-moon-affect-the-earths-climate)? What about effects of [vegetation like forests](http://www.forestfacts.org/level_1.htm#5)?)