# Where to start, if I would like to run a planet climate simulation?

Tags: simulations, planets, weather, exoplanets, climate-science

I would like to understand the math behind it, and maybe write an own climate simulator program. I know, that it is a really hard subject. But I'm curious, and I would like to learn more about it. But I cannot really find articles about it. I just need hints, where to start.

With the following input parameters:

- Type of sun/suns
- Details of the orbit
- Rotation/size/composition of the planet
- Atmosphere details
- Terrain (heightmap)
- liquid on the planet ( for example water )

I would like to calculate, that how will this planet likely look like, and find out some details about it's climate.

There was a similar question, but it was not answered: [How can I make a simple climate simulator?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/104866/how-can-i-make-a-simple-climate-simulator)

Comment: The question you linked was closed as "too broad" for this site, and I am afraid the same fate will befall this one. Because a good answer to this question would fill a book.

Comment: I am not looking for exact answers. I just want to know, where should I start

Comment: Climate models are complicated -- *really* complicated.  To make a start you will need a degree in a very numerate discipline (Physics is good) and then some postgraduate qualification in meteorology so you can make sense of the literature, and numerical methods / programming.  Then start with some reasonable numerical climate modelling text (I could find some suggestions) and work into the literature.  You will need a supercomputer.

Comment: If you are willing to ignore details, you can simply integrate the energy received from the sun - minus the energy emitted from earth through infrared heat radiation. Next you'd try to find a correlation between various factors, and the infrared heat radiation. Hint (amount of CO2, methane and other climate gases correlate greatly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking a bit into this I can tell you that even the best groups in the world can not do all of what you wanted with your bullet points: The problem is extremly complex: even if you could model a system with such a parameter space: simulation would be extremly expensive because of the extremly complex physics and high resolution required.

I do not know how much you researched this so maybe the following points are not new to you: You could search for "Exoplanet clima simulation" or "General Circulation Model/Global Climate Models (GCM)", "NASA/GISS general circulation model (GCM)".

Here would be one presentation on exoplanet clima simulations and in it are references for further reading: http://www.astro.ex.ac.uk/exoclimes/2010/talks/Forget_exoclimes10.pdf.

Here an article about NASA Climate Studies [Part 1](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/research/features/201504_nexss/)/[Part 2](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/research/features/201504_nexss/part2.html) and related [Simulating Martian Weather with the GISS GCM](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/research/briefs/allison_x1/).

This would be the webpage of [NASA Global Climate Modeling](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/projects/gcm/).

The above links/topics could be some points to start from. There seems to be much on the internet about that topic, but it does not look like a very easy topic to get into.