# Atmospheric Tides effect on atmospheric pressure

Tags: pressure, atmospheric-science, tidal-effect, weather

Regarding the atmospheric tides effect on the pressure, [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/201973/are-there-tides-in-the-atmosphere/201977#201977) (and the referenced sources) seem to point that such effect is very small.

However, this pressure prediction graph for my hometown seems to show periodic "bumps" on the daily pressure values.

[image]

Is this in fact due to the atmospheric tides or is it too "strong" (and thus explained by another effect)?

Comment: Are you sure measure of pressure is not noisy ? (wind, etc). And it also probably depends on variation of temperature in the day. And possibly, of the detail of front change and winds far above...

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET If it's noise, is a "prediction noise" because these are not acquired data. The fact that these bumps are periodic makes me think that they are not related to winds, and neither to temperature.